# Diluting reputation across stack exchange sites (combined reputation)

Tags: feature-request, reputation

Yesterday, I got an accepted answer on Super User (yeah!). But I thought I was on Stack Overflow. It takes a lot of time and effort to provide good answers, and I feel that effort is diluted if I have to spread it across multiple sites.

Shouldn't reputation across closely related sites be combined?

For example, I'm also on *[Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour)*, but there are SQL questions everywhere.

I'm not sure the fragmentation of sites is even that helpful. Last week I answered basically the same question on two different sites.

Should I ignore the other sites, and just concentrate on Stack Overflow?
That doesn't feel right. But I don't like diluting my effort either.

Comment: That wasn't my question.  My question is if there are separate sites.  Could there be a way of sharing reputation between them (aside from the 100 point bonus.  Or if there's not, are there strategies I can or (should?) employ to avoid diluting my efforts to gain rep.   Sorry, I'm like a little rat hunting for cheese.  And I don't like it when somebody moves it.

Comment: Site culture can be *very* different. Just because I have loads of rep on Stack Overflow, for example, doesn't mean I know the culture and on-topicness rules for server fault or dba. I shouldn't get to close and reopen questions there without actually knowing the place, so I have to "earn" my 3000 points like everybody else. The 100  points rep bonus is a compromise so you get access to the very basic features that are pretty much the same across all sites.

Answer (score 10):

**No.**  Answering a question between two sites shouldn't be regarded as equivalent, even if the subject is closely related.  Notwithstanding the herculean effort it'd take to make something like that work, what you're effectively saying is that it's okay to not participate in a specific community as long as you're really, really good in another one.

You should feel encouraged to participate on as many (or as few) sites as you like.  My advice would be to look at it as if you were participating in a community at your leisure, as opposed to a points grab.  That's not saying that I think you *are* doing that, but this does come across as such.

Comment: Herculean effort?  What are you talking about?   I'm only thinking of some sort of bubble up or trickle down mechanism.   Like 10 points gained on site B equals 2 points on A (where A is the parent of B or vice versa, or how ever you want to define related sites, with what ever ratio seems appropriate    Related site points could be award daily (or some other period).   I think such mechanism would encourage multi-site / cross site participation.   As it is now, I am somewhat discourage from wandering off stack overflow, to a more specific sites.

Comment: On a network with 60+ distinct communities, hundreds of thousands of users, and millions of daily page views, the tiniest change tends to become a herculean effort. There's myriad of things to be aware of, side effects and unintended consequences to be considered, etc...

Comment: @DarrelLee:  As said before, you can do kind of what you like.  You don't have to wander off of SO if you don't want to participate in other communities, but if you do, just treat them like they're a new instance.  You've got a clean-ish slate over there and you should be able to participate in that community should its topic suit you well.  Not having certain privileges is a bummer at times, but participating in good and meaningful ways will help bridge that gap.